# Lambda expression compare boolean as false results in NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I can't seem to figure out how to compare boolean values in a C# lambda expression for EF4. I've tried:

```
cl.Where(c => c.Received == false);
```

and this:

```
cl.Where(c => !c.Received);
```

and this:

```
cl.Where(c => c.Received.Equals(false));
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value
of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid')
are supported in this context.
```

After spending a good amount of time researching this I'm still missing something. I'm fairly new to Lambdas so [pointers](http://xkcd.com/138/) would be appreciated.

**Edit2:** more code re:comment

```
int bar = 42;
var cl = db.foo.Where(c => c.baz.Equals(bar));
//codez (just an if statement)
cl.Where(c => c.Received == false).OrderByDescending(c => c.dateAdded);
```

That's it. Even if I remove the orderby it still doesn't work

**Edit3:**

Solution:

```
int bar = 42;
var cl = db.foo.Where(c => c.baz == bar);
cl.Where(c => c.Received == false).OrderByDescending(c => c.dateAdded);
```

Comment: The error is probably in the other part of your statement. Could you post the rest of the line from which you do a call, and a few more frames off the stack trace?

Comment: What @dasblinkenlight says is correct.  THe first 2 methods will work fine for comparing booleans in EF 4

Comment: thanks for the quick response @dasblinkenlight I've added some of the surrounding code and the stack trace

Comment: Have you maped you database correctly? 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399596.aspx][1]

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399596.aspx

Comment: Are you sure it's the `Received` line, and not the other `Where` condition? Also, sanity check. Check that `Received` really is a boolean.

Comment: sanity is confirmed `received` is a bit in SQL and a boolean in EF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is most likely in the `c.baz.Equals(bar)` line. If you change it to

```
var cl = db.foo.Where(c => c.baz.Equals(bar)).ToList();
```

you should see the exception thrown on that line, because you force evaluation of the `IQueryable<T>`.

Instead of comparing objects, you should compare their IDs, like this:

(edited to reflect the conversation in the comments and changes to the OP)

```
var cl = db.foo.Where(c => c.baz == bar.id);
```

Comment: You can compare objects in linq? If its from the same instance of the datacontext.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight edited my coded again. Bar is an int variable. Does this affect your code?

Comment: @Niklas Until you convert it to `IEnumerable<T>`, it's not LINQ yet: it is in the EF's world, where `IQueryable<T>` gets translated to SQL.

Comment: @Eonasdan I see - I did not realize it was an int. Did you try using `==` instead of `Equals`?

Comment: ah! that did it! why does that make a difference? As I said, I'm pretty new to `lambda`.

Comment: @Eonasdan Lambda's not what's doing it, it is the difference between queryables and enumerables. Queryables get translated to SQL, while enumerables are evaluated in memory. In the process of translating your query to SQL, EF sees a function called `Equals` that takes `object` as an argument. It then tries to convert it literally to SQL, but it does not work, because there is no function like that in RDBMS. `==`, however, is built-in, so EF knows how to translate it correctly.

Comment: I see. Thanks for answer my questions. Have a merry Christmas

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of  `Received` ? `Where` close need a predicate(a function that return Boolean) in order to act upon every element in the list and return those that satisfy the condition. From the error message it seems the `Received` in not primitive type. You need to cast it to boolean if you for sure know its boolean.